# Looping through a Table and setting the value for a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-update

people...

I'm a total SQL Server Newbie and have the following problem. I need to iterate over a table and update one column. In this column i want to set an Integer value. In the following row i want to add 1 to the value. So that the column rows look like this:

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

Whats the easiest way to do this?

Thanks! :-)

Comment: It should say Hello people...

Comment: What is the purpose of this column?  Is it to create a unique id?

Comment: Need more information. In what order do you want to "iterate over the table"? By definition, a table is an unordered set of rows, so you need to indicate how the code will determine which row should be #1, which should be #2, etc. Also, do you plan to update the table again every time you add a new row?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
UPDATE YourTable
    SET YourColumn = YourColumn + 1
```

Comment: I'm looking for something like:

Comment: I'm looking for something like:
first row, Column Value: 1
second row, Column Value: 2
third row, Column Value: 3

Comment: You need to define which row is the "first row"... as I mentioned earlier, a table is not "ordered" unless you define it as such using an ORDER BY clause. Tell us how you identify first row, second row, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand SQL and set-based operations. You don't loop through a table, you update sets of information at once.

If you just need a sequential number, you could do something like this:

```
with cte as (select primarykey, row_number() over (order by primarykey) rn from yourtable)
update yourtable 
set yourcol = rn 
from yourtable 
join cte on yourtable.pk = cte.primarykey
```

But you should really understand the basics before you try writing advanced queries. If you have to ask how to (or if you can) iterate through a table, you probably shouldn't be doing it.

Comment: I wonderd if this can be done with Transact SQL or Stored Procedures from the MS SQL Server...

Comment: that is transact sql and it'll run in mssql

Comment: sorry, if that was misunderstood... so could you point me to a tutorial page or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to actually loop through (not sure that you actually do), here is a link on how you can do it 1 row at a time. The second section walks you through creating a WHILE loop:

[SQL Loop](http://www.sqloptimizationsschool.com/Pages/Advanced%20Concepts/Loops%20vs.%20Cursors.aspx)